# Trigger Brightcove video play on image click and hide it when video is done

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, brightcove

I'm trying to play a video on image click and hide it when video is done, and so far I have a structure like this:

```
<a href="#">
    <div style="display:none"></div>
    <div class="overlay_play_big"></div>
    <div class="overlay_label">
        <span class="title">Bones</span><br />
        <span class="desc">Season 8, Episode 19</span>
    </div>

    <!--
    By use of this code snippet, I agree to the Brightcove Publisher T and C 
    found at https://accounts.brightcove.com/en/terms-and-conditions/. 
    -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://admin.brightcove.com/js/BrightcoveExperiences.js"></script>

    <object id="myExperience2768811593001" class="BrightcoveExperience">
        <param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF" />
        <param name="width" value="470" />
        <param name="height" value="292" />
        <param name="playerID" value="2764056952001" />
        <param name="playerKey" value="AQ~~,AAACg0nERbk~,bDrRQnHHnTJYYUzl4RqDhsPQ_y-ladJF" />
        <param name="isVid" value="true" />
        <param name="dynamicStreaming" value="true" />
        <param name="includeAPI" value="true" /> 
        <param name="templateLoadHandler" value="onTemplateLoaded" /> 
        <param name="templateReadyHandler" value="onTemplateReady" />
        <param name="@videoPlayer" value="2768811593001" />
    </object>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var player, modVP;

        function onTemplateLoaded(experienceID) {
          player = brightcove.api.getExperience(experienceID);
          modVP = player.getModule(brightcove.api.modules.APIModules.VIDEO_PLAYER);
        }

        function onTemplateReady(evt) {
          modVP.addEventListener(brightcove.api.events.MediaEvent.COMPLETE, onComplete);
        }

        function onComplete(evt) {
          alert("Video ended");
        }
    </script>

    <!-- 
    This script tag will cause the Brightcove Players defined above it to be created as soon
    as the line is read by the browser. If you wish to have the player instantiated only after
    the rest of the HTML is processed and the page load is complete, remove the line.
    -->
    <script type="text/javascript">brightcove.createExperiences();</script>
    <!-- End of Brightcove Player -->
</a>
```

I want to trigger video playback on click of the `overlay_play_big` div. I'm using the Brightcove API but even this simple alert won't work. The video ends and nothing happens. How can I do this, or am I making a mistake ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This below code will work as expected..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Player Event Tester</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="http://admin.brightcove.com/js/BrightcoveExperiences.js"></script>

<div id="player" style="float: left">
<object id="myExperience1754261637001" class="BrightcoveExperience">
  <param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF" />
  <param name="width" value="480" />
  <param name="height" value="270" />
  <param name="playerID" value="2549948545001" />
  <param name="playerKey" value="AQ~~,AAABmA9XpXk~,-Kp7jNgisreVadKjzdyJfLcfukyXcGqB" />
  <param name="isVid" value="true" />
  <param name="isUI" value="true" />
  <param name="dynamicStreaming" value="true" />
  <param name="includeAPI" value="true" />
  <param name="templateLoadHandler" value="myTemplateLoaded" />
  <param name="templateReadyHandler" value="onTemplateReady">
  <param name="@videoPlayer" value="1754261637001" />
</object>
<div>
<button id="changeVideo" onclick="changeVideo()">Change Video</button>
<div class="overlay_play_big">Play</div>
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
brightcove.createExperiences();
</script>
<div id="log" style="float: left">
<div id="positionLog"></div>
<div id="eventLog"></div>
</div>
<script>
var myTemplateLoaded, onTemplateReady, player, modVP, modExp, modCon, previousVideoID=0, currentVideo, videosToSwap=new Array(1754261637001,1754261438001); //videos we will swap

myTemplateLoaded = function (experienceID) {
    player = brightcove.api.getExperience(experienceID);
    modVP = player.getModule(brightcove.api.modules.APIModules.VIDEO_PLAYER);
    modExp = player.getModule(brightcove.api.modules.APIModules.EXPERIENCE);
    modCon = player.getModule(brightcove.api.modules.APIModules.CONTENT);
}

onTemplateReady = function (evt) {
    modVP.getCurrentVideo(function (dto) {
    });
    modVP.addEventListener(brightcove.api.events.MediaEvent.BEGIN, onMediaEventFired);
    modVP.addEventListener(brightcove.api.events.MediaEvent.CHANGE, onMediaEventFired);
    modVP.addEventListener(brightcove.api.events.MediaEvent.COMPLETE, onMediaEventFired);
    modVP.addEventListener(brightcove.api.events.MediaEvent.ERROR, onMediaEventFired);
    modVP.addEventListener(brightcove.api.events.MediaEvent.PLAY, onMediaEventFired);
    modVP.addEventListener(brightcove.api.events.MediaEvent.PROGRESS, onMediaProgressFired);
    modVP.addEventListener(brightcove.api.events.MediaEvent.STOP, onMediaEventFired);
}

function onMediaEventFired(evt) {
   document.getElementById("eventLog").innerHTML += "MEDIA EVENT: " + evt.type + " fired at position: " + evt.position + "<BR>";
   if (evt.type === "mediaComplete") {
       //changeVideo();
       alert('ended');
   }
}

function onMediaProgressFired(evt) {
   document.getElementById("positionLog").innerHTML = "CURRENT POSITION: " + evt.position;
}

function changeVideo() {
   modVP.getCurrentVideo(currentVideoCallback);
}

function currentVideoCallback(currentVideo) {
   document.getElementById("positionLog").innerHTML = "";
   document.getElementById("eventLog").innerHTML = "";

   if (currentVideo.id == videosToSwap[0]) {
      modVP.loadVideoByID(videosToSwap[1]);
   } else {
      modVP.loadVideoByID(videosToSwap[0]);
   }
}

$('.overlay_play_big').on('click',function(){
      modVP.play();
});

</script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Still not working for me , I copied your code in the separated html document and api still dont work , is there any other thing to to except this ?

Comment: K which ever browser u checked into try it online (i.e put into xampp or apache server works for me in ie9,chrome,safari)  ...

Comment: Ok I just found whats the problem , it needs to be hosted in case to work , i was testing from the local , tnx !